# Firebase Rules for all users

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

How to allow users to read and write in the "posters" database

I want it to be for the authenticated only.

This are my rules

```
{
   "rules":{
      "posters":{
         ".read":true,
         ".write": true
      },
      "users": {
         "$uid": {
            ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
            ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: What's your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are asking how to protect data under the "posters" for reading and writing only by authenticated users, use the information from the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#authentication):

> The predefined `auth` variable in the rules is null before authentication takes place.

So, just check that `auth` is not null;

```
  "posters":{
     ".read": "auth != null",
     ".write": "auth != null"
  },
```